# Trying to implement append in my own shell Linux

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to implement append command in my own shell.
I succeeded to append to existing file but whenever I'm trying to append to file doesn't exist it makes a file without any permission (not read and not write)

```
   if (append) {
        fd = open(outfile,'a'); 
        lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
        close (STDOUT_FILENO) ; 
        dup(fd); 
        close(fd); 
        /* stdout is now appended */
    }
```

What should I do to make a file with permissions
?

Comment: The basic call is: `fd = open(outfile,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,0644);`. No `lseek` necessary. And, I'd use `dup2`, just to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open()` system call doesn't use a character constant to indicate 'append'.  Read the POSIX specification for [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) — and look at `O_APPEND` etc.  You need more flags than just `O_APPEND`, and you need three arguments to `open()` if you want to create the file if it doesn't exist (`O_CREAT`), etc.

```
if (append)
{
    fd = open(outfile, O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (fd < 0)
        …deal with error…
}
```

You can write `0644` as `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH` but the octal is shorter and (after 30+ years practice) a lot easier to read.  You can add write permissions for group (`S_IWGRP`) and others (`S_IWOTH`) if you like (`0666` in octal), but unless you know you want group members and others to modify the files, it is safer to omit those — for all it goes against historical precedent.  Users can and should set the shell `umask` value to `022` to prevent group and others from being able to write to files by default, but there's no harm (IMO) in being secure without that.